# Phpunit not running Symfony tests

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I'm trying to run a few functional tests in Symfony, but they won't work. Running phpunit targeting the whole AppBundle results in "No tests executed", and targeting it to a specific class gets me this error:

```
$ phpunit tests/AppBundle/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'tests/AppBundle/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest' could not be found in '/home/.../tests/AppBundle/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php'. in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:107
```

Later I found out unit tests are not working as well, same error message.

The functional test I'm trying to run is Symfony Best Practices example:

```
// tests/AppBundle/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider urlProvider
     */
    public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }

    public function urlProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array('/'),
            array('/team'),
            // ...
        );
    }
}
```

I have tried targeting another class, the DefaultControllerTest, but the same exception showed up.
I'm running phpunit version 6.0.7 (downloaded as Phar), Symfony 3.2 and PHP 7.0. I've had to require phpunit/phpunit ^4.8 with composer since this exception appeared:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /home/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php on line 23
```

I have tried using `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of the .phar version, and at least it detects the tests, but all of them have weird results.
It doesn't recognize expectException, for instance:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\AppBundle\Util\Chart\ChartDataTest::expectException()
```

In functional tests, it doesn't seem to reach any path, even though they are perfectly accessible through the browser:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist
1) Tests\AppBundle\ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest::testPageIsSuccessful with data set #0 ('/')
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Is it a version issue?

`composer.json` file:

```
    {
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.2-dev"
    }
}
   }
```

Here's `phpunit.xml.dist`: (currently in root folder, unmodified since project creation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Can you post (at least the autoloader part of) the `composer.json` files?

Comment: youve not told phpunit where the autoloader is. You need to create a phpunit.xml file.

Comment: @DevDonkey doesn't phpunit.xml.dist take care of this?

Comment: Only if you tell it to use it

Comment: @DevDonkey With `-c phpunit.xml.dist` the result is the same

Comment: A small correction: I have noticed that not only functional tests but also unit tests are not working properly. The error message is different, however: `Cannot open file "tests/AppBundle/Util/Chart/ChartData.php`.

Comment: In your config, you have this : `<directory>tests</directory>`. Where did you put your tests folder ? In src ? By the way, I think the syntax is `phpunit -c /path/to/folder/containing/phpunit.xml.dist tests/AppBundle/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php`. You must specify the path to the folder containing phpunit.xml.dist (app/ if you don't change anything)

Comment: @mickdev My tests are in the `tests/` folder, as recommended by the documentation. `phpunit.xml.dist` is in the root folder (I don't know whether it is the right place to be, but that's where it spawned when I created the project with composer).

Comment: You're using Symfony2 or Symfony3 (the tag say Symfony2)? Because, when I look at my Symfony2 projects, `phpunit.xml.dist`  is in app folder and tests are configurated like this `<directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>` and it work with this cmd : `phpunit -c /app src/AppBundle/Tests/somedummytest.php`. Anyway, I think your issue is related to the path you provide to phpUnit

Comment: I used the same `phpunit.xml.dist`, the same `composer.json` and the same test class in the same directory. After composer update running `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` from the root directory successfully found and ran the tests. Can you confirm you've run composer update and are running the tests from the root directory?

Comment: @mickdev sorry, I'm using Symfony3, I guess the tag came out wrong. @mickadoo I ran `composer update` and ran `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`. Did your test for application availability come out successful? Mine are still not reaching the paths specified. Could it be because my php cli is 7.0 and the composer.json specifies php>=5.9?

Comment: Well sorry, folks, I guess PHPUnit IS working after all - at least the composer version, the PHAR one still gets "No tests detected".
I tried creating a new Symfony project in the same environment, and the results came ok. The thing is, it doesn't work with my own controller: even though it gets me code 200 through the browser, it comes as 500 through phpunit. I guess the question is different, now; I'm not familiar with the protocol, should I close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a version issue, it seems: for some reason when the Symfony project was created the PHP version was set to 5.5, which restrained more recent PHPUnit versions. When I downloaded the PHAR version, it was version 6.0 (which did not work with the version of the project I was working with - PHP 5.6 - but was runnable since my php-cli was 7.0). PHPUnit 4.8, which came through composer, did run the ApplicationAvailability tests ok (this, at least, is something weird happening with my code, I will find out about that later), but still had awkward behaviour (understandable, since it's practically deprecated). When I configured `composer.json` with PHP 5.6, everything was clear: PHPUnit upgraded to 5.7, which works perfectly with PHP 5.6. Thanks @mickadoo for pointing out that the tests did run ok.